# Installing Resin on Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, resin

Has anyone has success installing Resin 4 on Snow Leopard? I get linker errors when I try it which are maddening.

Comment: +1 for the madness tag! Found this on Google: http://angry-fly.com/post.cfm/fixing-railo-and-resin-on-snow-leopard

Comment: and this: http://www.nabble.com/Resin-on-Snow-Leopard:-Install-scripts-need-updating--td25446480.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like [this resin bug](http://bugs.caucho.com/view.php?id=3685), which just has been fixed in the source. the fix will be released with the upcoming 4.0.2. for now, you could try the Resin 4.0 snapshot from http://www.caucho.com/download/ .